# How to use NuGet to install Boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, nuget

I am new to Visual Studio.
I have cloned a git project that needs Boost.Test.

When I try to install Boost with the NuGet console (inside MSVC) I get this error below although the package clearly exists.

Is this the correct way to install Boost to use in a Visual Studio C++ project?

```
PM> Find-Package boost

Id                                  Versions                                 Description                                                                                                                           
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                                                                           
boost                               {1.79.0}                                 boost                                                                                                                                 
boost_filesystem-vc140              {1.79.0}                                 boost_filesystem-vc140. Compiler: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.                                                                        
boost_system-vc140                  {1.79.0}                                 boost_system-vc140. Compiler: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.                                                                            
boost_date_time-vc140               {1.79.0}                                 boost_date_time-vc140. Compiler: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.                                                                         
boost_filesystem-vc120              {1.79.0}                                 boost_filesystem-vc120. Compiler: Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.                                                                        
boost_chrono-vc120                  {1.79.0}                                 boost_chrono-vc120. Compiler: Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.                                                                            
boost_date_time-vc141               {1.79.0}                                 boost_date_time-vc141. Compiler: Visual Studio 2017 15.9.45.                                                                          
boost_system-vc120                  {1.79.0}                                 boost_system-vc120. Compiler: Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.                                                                            
boost_thread-vc120                  {1.79.0}                                 boost_thread-vc120. Compiler: Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.                                                                            
boost_system-vc141                  {1.79.0}                                 boost_system-vc141. Compiler: Visual Studio 2017 15.9.45.                                                                             
boost_date_time-vc120               {1.79.0}                                 boost_date_time-vc120. Compiler: Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.                                                                         
boost_regex-vc140                   {1.79.0}                                 boost_regex-vc140. Compiler: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.                                                                             
boost_thread-vc141                  {1.79.0}                                 boost_thread-vc141. Compiler: Visual Studio 2017 15.9.45.                                                                             
boost_chrono-vc141                  {1.79.0}                                 boost_chrono-vc141. Compiler: Visual Studio 2017 15.9.45.                                                                             
boost_regex-vc142                   {1.79.0}                                 boost_regex-vc142. Compiler: Visual Studio 2019 16.11.11.                                                                             
boost_log-vc140                     {1.79.0}                                 boost_log-vc140. Compiler: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.                                                                               
boost_random-vc140                  {1.79.0}                                 boost_random-vc140. Compiler: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.                                                                            
boost_regex-vc120                   {1.79.0}                                 boost_regex-vc120. Compiler: Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.                                                                             
boost_filesystem-vc141              {1.79.0}                                 boost_filesystem-vc141. Compiler: Visual Studio 2017 15.9.45.                                                                         
boost_serialization-vc140           {1.79.0}                                 boost_serialization-vc140. Compiler: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.                                                                     
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.1981777


PM>  Install-Package boost -Version 1.79.0
Install-Package : Project 'Default' is not found.
At line:1 char:2
+  Install-Package boost -Version 1.79.0
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
PM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a test according to your description and it installed boost correctly.
[image]

In your code the error shows that “Project 'Default' is not found”.

Please check this drop down box “Defalut project” in Package Manager Console, this error may occur if the project you selected has already been deleted or unload.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, indeed, the "Default project" box is empty but also the drop down menu is empty. I cloned from a repository first, but it seems that doesn't create a project in itself. So, I created a project from the existing directory and then it worked. Thank you!